# Handling multiple records in dataframe - Java Spark

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark

I have the below dataframe.

```
Column_1 Column_2
1        A
1        X
2        X
3        B
3        X
4        C
4        D
```

In the above dataframe, there can be multiple records for same value in column 1. 
I have to only remove those records which has more than entry and has an X in the column_2. If column 2 has 2 different values like C and D, i have to retain them. Only when a record has multiple entries but one of those entries has X, i have to remove them from my dataframe. Please note that if there is only one record with X in column_2, then we should not be removing that record.

Expected Output:

```
Column_1 Column_2
1        A
2        X
3        B
4        C
4        D
```

Kindly let me know if this can be achieved in Java Spark. I was able to remove the X records altogether, but not sure how to achieve the above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete working code with explanation inline,
input csv looks like

```
Column_1,Column_2
1,A
1,X
2,X
3,B
3,X
4,C
4,D
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

public class DropDups {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read()
                .option("header", "true")
                .csv("src/main/resources/duplicateRec.csv");

        ds.show();

/* Ouputs
+--------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2|
+--------+--------+
|       1|       A|
|       1|       X|
|       2|       X|
|       3|       B|
|       3|       X|
|       4|       C|
|       4|       D|
+--------+--------+
 */

        //Group by Column_1 and collect set of elements from Column_2 and remove 'X' from the set
        ds = ds.groupBy(ds.col("Column_1")).agg(
                array_remove(collect_set(ds.col("Column_2")), lit("X")).as("Column_2_list"));

        // if the set is empty then ["X"] else the actual set
        ds = ds.withColumn("Column_2_array",
                when(size(ds.col("Column_2_list")).equalTo(0), lit("X".split(",")))
                        .otherwise(ds.col("Column_2_list")));

        //Replace the column and drop the extra columns
        ds.withColumn("Column_2", explode(ds.col("Column_2_array")))
                .drop("Column_2_list", "Column_2_array")
                .show();
/* Ouputs
+--------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2|
+--------+--------+
|       3|       B|
|       1|       A|
|       4|       C|
|       4|       D|
|       2|       X|
+--------+--------+
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Working as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's scala but java will look almost identical:

```
df.withColumn("id",row_number().over(Window.orderBy("c_1").partitionBy("c_1")))
  .where(!('c_2==="X" and 'id > 1))

+----+----+
| c_1| c_2|
+----+----+
|   1|   A|
|   3|   B|
|   4|   C| 
|   4|   D|
|   2|   X|
+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I prefer the other answer because I cannot really be sure if X will be in the second row only. It might be in second or first.